# Rewrite rule to map locations to static files

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

What I want to do it rewrite urls for a bunch of static pages in a locations folder such that

/london

maps to the physical file if it exist in the locations folder eg.

/locations/london.aspx

Is this possible with url rewrite. I can't get the rule to work.

```
<rule name="Rewrite Locations">
    <match url="^([_0-9a-z-]+)/*" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="/locations/{REQUEST_FILENAME}.aspx" matchType="IsFile" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/locations/{R:1}.aspx" />
</rule>
```

Many thanks,

Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the IsFile to work you have to pass the right physical path and not the virtual path, you can do something like:

```
<rule name="Locations" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([_0-9a-z-]+)/*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH}locations\{R:1}.aspx" matchType="IsFile" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/locations/{R:1}.aspx" />
</rule>
```